# Adding Javascript on Initial Load after updating UpdatePanels

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, alert, onload

On my Page_Load command for a page, I have a couple of tests that are performed before the screen is displayed with an alert box displaying if the user cannot access the screen.

```
     If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

   UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(ctl)
   UpdatePanel1.Update

   UpdatePanel2.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(ctl)
   UpdatePanel2.Update

    If ScreenAccessible = False

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "denied", "alert('Access Denied');", True)
    End If : End If
```

I would assume that based on the order of the procedure above, the update panels should update first, and then the alert message will follow.

However, the alert message shows up first, with the update panels empty. When I click the OK button on the alert box, the update panels are correctly render.

How do I allow the JavaScript alert box to appears after the update panels have rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
If ScreenAccessible = False

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "denied", _
        "setTimeout(function(){alert('Access Denied');},300);" , True)

End If
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp